# How do i convert SQL query to hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

When i try to run this i get "Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class".

SQL:

```
select c.*, count(s.student_id)
from class_tbl c    
left join students_tbl s on c.class_id = s.student_id
group by c.class_id
```

This is what I tried but seems not to work - HQL:

```
select new Class(class, count(students.studentId))
from Class as class    
left join class.students as students
group by class.classId
```

I have on my object Class a constructor like:

```
public Class(Class class, long studentCount){
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved word in Java. Be careful about that.

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use Class as a class name, it's a reserved word.

I think your HQL should look like this:

```
"select new map(class, count(students.studentId) as studentCount) from Class class left 
join fetch class.students students group by class.classId");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion and now I get this other error message "query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list"

Comment: Try giving the students a name <code>left join class.students students</code>

Comment: If forgot to add fetch to the left join, this might also be the source of the error. So the full hql: "select new map(class, count(students.studentId) as studentCount) from Class class left 
join fetch class.students students group by class.classId");

Comment: I tried that as well and it is not working here is the hiberante mapping :
<set name="students" table="students_tbl" inverse="true" order-by="class_id" fetch="join" lazy="false">   
  <key column="class_id " />
  <element column="student_id" type="integer"/>
</set>